# How many days has it been since an entry is put in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Model.

```
const GoalSchema = new Schema({
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how long it has been since the creation of this object, I tried the following:

```
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ;
const temp = new Date();
const diff = (temp - goal.Date.getTime());
diff /= oneDay;
```

Here the goal is the Goal Object I'm receiving from mongoose. Can you help me figure how many days have passed?

Comment: I think you shouldn't give a name `Date` as a property on your db. I always use as `created_at`, `updated_at` and such. After you get your `goal` object your `goal.Date` is gonna be `timestamp` not a JS `Date` object so there won't be a `getTime` function if you didn't cast is as. to find the diff just  use this insead. `const diff = Date.now() - goal.Date;` Hope this helps

Comment: @HalilÇakar I get NaN when I console.log diff. I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. 
`
const diff = (Date.now - goal.Date);
console.log(diff);
`

Comment: `Date.now()` call it as function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Mongoose timestamp feature.

```
const GoalSchema = new Schema({
    yourFields: String
}, {timestamps: true});
```

This will automatically create createdAt and updatedAt fields on the MongoDB document.

Then to get the difference between dates. Use the following code

```
let createdDate = new Date(doc.createdAt);
let currentDate = new Date();
let timeDif = Math.abs(createdDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime());

let differentDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Or you could use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
let createdDate = moment(doc.createdAt);
let currentDate = moment()
createdDate.diff(currentDate, 'days')
```

Comment: Can you suggest a proper way of finding out no. of days since the object has been created?

Comment: @KenAdams edited answers to include calculation of the difference between dates.